# How can I calculate scattering cross section of Yukawa potential classically?

Tags: classical-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction#Classical_potential

Here is classical form of Yukawa potential.

I want to calculate classical scattering cross section of this potential analytically(theoretically).

Is there any analytic solution of this?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you want to derive the Yukawa potential classically?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57640/classical-scattering-of-two-particles-by-a-yukawa-potential

Comment: @Avantgarde no i mean that i want to derive cross section of yukawa potential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that an analytical solution doesn't exist.  The usual technique for computing classical scattering cross-section (at a fixed energy $E$) involves first calculating the scattering angle $\Theta$ as a function of the impact parameter $b$.  This is done by calculating the integral
$$
\Theta = \pi - 2 \int_{\rho}^\infty \frac{(b/r^2)\, dr}{\sqrt{1 - (b^2/r^2) - U(r)/E}},
$$
where $U(r)$ is the potential and $\rho$ is defined as the distance of closest approach:
$$
\frac{U(\rho)}{E} + \frac{b^2}{\rho^2} = 1.
$$
The integral above is ugly enough for a power-law potential like $U(r) \propto r^n$; to the best of my knowledge it can only be evaluated for certain values of $n$.  The prospect of dropping $U(r) = \alpha e^{-\mu r}/r$ into that integral and trying to evaluate it does not fill me with joy;  and I'm pretty sure that the equation defining $\rho$ is a transcendental equation (i.e., no closed-form expression) in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think i should try numerically with your equation.